# Can I use bitwise operators instead of conditional operators in C?

Tags: c, syntax, bitwise-operators, conditional-operator

Can I use & and | instead of && and || in the C language family ? This won't work with objects ofcourse. Is there any difference ? If there isn't, then why do the conditional operators exist ?

For example:

```
if (3 && 5) // true
if (3 & 5) // also true
```

Comment: Bitwise operators don't short-circuit.

Comment: Bitwise operators and Logical operators are different. What do you mean with "instead of"?  Show some examples

Comment: Short circuit is a big difference.

Comment: || and && are logical operators, they return true or false, & and | are bitwise, they don't just return 0 or 1

Comment: `1 && 2` is true, `1 & 2` is 0 (false)

Comment: There's a huge difference between `&` and `&&` operators.  For example:  `0x01 & 0x10` is `0`, `0x01 && 0x10` is `1`.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I was about to write something similar as an answer :) But I guess you should do it with an addition of short-circuiting..

Comment: You can turn all the values into boolean 0 and 1 using `!!`, then `&` and `|` will behave like non-short-circuiting versions of `&&` and `||`. For example, `1 & 2` is `0`, but `!!1 & !!2` is `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in comments:

> `1 && 2` is true, `1 & 2` is false.

Also,

> Bitwise operators don't short-circuit.

Comment: Neither `true` nor `false` are C keywords.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That is why they do not appear with a fixed font in my answer.

Comment: WT... first time I see an "wiki" answer. How can it be done?

Comment: @LPs: There's a checkmark to the bottom right of the answer text box. You won't get rep from the answer but open it up for everyone to edit.

Comment: @mouviciel *That is why they do not appear with a fixed font in my answer.*  Someone unfamiliar with C isn't going to notice that.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Why would it matter?

Comment: @EugeneSh *Why would it matter?*  Because the logical operators `&&` and `||` produce either `0` or `1`, not some amorphous "true" or "false", and the bitwise operators produce the full bitwise-or or -and of the two operands.  Additionally, the logical '||' can short circuit evaluation of the second operand, while the bitwise `|` does not.  They are significantly different.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: We have been using "true" as colloquial synonym for "something not equal to `0`" in C for ages, *because* there is no `true` keyword with a more well-defined meaning... (Of course, now there is `<stdbool.h>` defining the *macro* `true` to `1`...)

Comment: @DevSolar Colloquialisms are fine in casual conversation.  But precision matters in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (3 & 5) // also true
```

Yes because the result of bitwise `&` is `1`

Using 8 bit:

```
0b00000101 &
0b00000011
------------
0b00000001
```

But what `if ( 2 & 5 )`

```
0b00000010 &
0b00000101
------------
0b00000000
```

So it is `false` while `if ( 2 && 5)` still `true`;

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators and bitwise operators are quite different. Logical operators return a boolean value (either 0 or 1) while bitwise operators return an integer based on applying that bitwise operator bit by bit. Example: 15 & 8 = 8, while 15 && 8 = 1. Syntactically you can use bitwise operators inplace of logical operators but semantically it will be wrong.